# Windows 10 can't find programs in subfolder

Tags: windows, windows-10, search, start-menu, windows-search

On my Windows 10 machine I can't find applications which are in sub-folders,
when I am clicking Windows key and typing the program name.

[Example - I have a regular Skype and Skype for business:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/706MN.jpg)
but I when I am typing "Skype" I can only find program Skype for business which is not in subfolder.

How to change this behavior? On my old machine everything is working ok, and I can search for any installed programs.

Comment: You mention you have old Machine. Is that having windows 10?

Comment: Yes, the second older comes with identical Windows 10 Pro, and work as expeced

Comment: Run winver in both system see the build number are same in both system..

Comment: both sysems are updated to the newest versiom from Windows Update

Comment: You are sure that both are having build version 1703. I wanted to cross pls check again if u can

Comment: Yes, 1703 on both

Answer (score 0):

When you Hit on Start and Type Skype Only it will list search from **apps & documents & web** only by default.

[image: See this Image]

If you want to search in folders you have type **`folder: skype`**

[image: Search Folder]

If the app shortcut represent in folder. In Given below path. It shows you inside the folder

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

Note: Skype for Business, Google chrome some other apps wont come with folder in it.  The shortcut is added in **Start Menu\Programs** without any folder. In that case first preference will go to shortcut file next to folder.